# How do I assign attachments file to create post using Wordpress REST API in python?

Tags: python, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I use this [tutorial 1](https://gist.github.com/openroomxyz/73359be882d2ee22c761a9e24a060b78) ,[tutorial 2](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/)  and create new posts in python code, with below json:

```
    post = {
    'title'    :  title, 
    'status'   : 'publish', 
    'content'  :  'Hello this is content of my post.',
    'categories': 5, # category ID
    'date'   : '2020-01-05T10:00:00',
    }
```

The code work well done. The code create new post with content `Hello this is content of my post.` .

But I want add three PDF file(uploaded) to content new post.

I known file `1.pdf`  id is 324, file `2.pdf`  id is 325, file `3.pdf`  id is 326.

How can I attach three PDF file uploaded to new post?